# Google ads are showing small on mobile

Tags: google-adsense

i am facing a problem with the mobile version of my site. The advertisements are showing very small. I have tried custom sizes, 300x250(mobile optimized), but still, the ads are small. I see sites with bigger ads compared to  my mobile view. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that I was missing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```